# What exactly do push() and pop() do when not attached to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm definitely not that good at coding, and I have a question. I know that when you use the push() or pop() function, they add or remove something to or from the end of an array, respectively. However, I've seen them used on their own, not attached to an array. Can someone explain what this does and why it works? I'm using the p5 library to make things easier for me, if that makes any difference.

As an example, instead of declaring an array and using push or pop on it:

```js
var array = [];
array.push("something");
```

What happens when I just do:

```
//code up here
push();
//code in here
pop();
//code down here
```

In the second piece of code, I'm not attaching push() or pop() to anything, and I'm wondering what exactly that does.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: See the p5.js documentation: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push

Comment: `pop()` gives a ReferenceError: 'pop' is not defined on my machine.

Comment: @JaredSmith They're P5 functions.

Comment: @Babis.amas I updated it to provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In P5js, the `push()` and `pop()` method are not supposed to be confused with `Array.push` and `Array.pop`. They are only procedures to do exactly like described in the P5js [reference | push](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push).

> The push() function saves the current drawing style settings and transformations, while pop() restores these settings. Note that these functions are always used together. They allow you to change the style and transformation settings and later return to what you had. When a new state is started with push(), it builds on the current style and transform information.

Answer (score 4):

They're used to save and restore the drawing state in p5.js. From the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push):

> The `push()` function saves the current drawing style settings and transformations, while `pop()` restores these settings. Note that these functions are always used together. They allow you to change the style and transformation settings and later return to what you had.

And it includes an example of code:

```
ellipse(0, 50, 33, 33); // Left circle

push(); // Start a new drawing state
strokeWeight(10);
fill(204, 153, 0);
translate(50, 0);
ellipse(0, 50, 33, 33); // Middle circle
pop(); // Restore original state

ellipse(100, 50, 33, 33); // Right circle
```

Comment: I thought it was a normal javascript function, and that's why I was so confused. On its own, I guess it's just for p5.js. Thanks!